# how do write code set interval and clear interval in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am writing functionality for to show hide loader gif and the data accordingly, in angular, plain javascript setInterval code doesn't work for $scope.showLoader=true and $scope.showResult = true; The last statement console.log('found the ...') works but first 2 statements (show hide) doesn't. the loader keep rotating and the data doesn't display.
Is angular $setTimeout would work?

```
        $scope.showLoader = true;
        $scope.showResult = false;

        var timer = setInterval(function(){

            if($scope.resultArray.length == 4) {
                clearInterval(timer);
                $scope.showResult = true;     // doesn't work               
                $scope.showLoader = false;    // doesn't work
                console.log('found all search results'); // it works

            }

        },200);
```

Comment: Why do you need the setInterval here? shouldn't there be some kind of callback on whatever is updating resultArray?

Comment: difficult to describe otherwise i wouldn't be here... just asking angular setInterval will work or not?

Comment: why negative comments before understanding the issue...?

Comment: Should be using `$watch` for this but most likely as Kevin points out this should be tied into your data updating logic

Comment: Sure, it would "work", it's just the wrong way to solve the problem. The `$scope.$apply` in the answer below will also "work", but again it's the wrong way to solve the problem.

Comment: I just upvoted your answer. I believe it is unacceptable to down-vote something just because someone does not understand the whole issue of the poster.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: I definitely understand the issue. There isn't enough information in the question to *correctly* solve this problem. you shouldn't be using a setInterval to figure out when something asynchronous is complete.

Comment: @superczan that is not the only reason for down votes. Value of question to future readers is also a reason

Comment: if i would write whole overview of my code it would took more time ...

Comment: @Kevin B, you are right but there is view where people don't know the better way to do that or they know but don't have enough time.

Comment: @sagSurya It's the $scope.$apply() issue. check my answer below for more details.

Comment: yah thanks! it would work i guess.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is a classic problem. Angular does not know that your variables showLoader and showResult have updated inside the timer. So, you need to let Angular "know". You need to set $scope.$apply() after setting these variables. This will work! Hope it helps you.

```
    $scope.showLoader = true;
    $scope.showResult = false;

    var timer = setInterval(function(){

        if($scope.resultArray.length == 4) {
            clearInterval(timer);
            $scope.showResult = true;     // doesn't work               
            $scope.showLoader = false;    // doesn't work
    $scope.$apply();
            console.log('found all search results'); // it works

        }

    },200);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could fix this by adding `$scope.$apply`.  The reason this does not currently work is that angular does not listen for changes made in asynchronous javascript, unless using certain angular methods like `$timeout`.  `$apply` allows you to tell angular that it needs to check for changes by triggering a digest cycle.  However, I think a better solution for this would be to use `$watch` instead.

```
$scope.$watch('resultArray', function(resultArray) {
   if(resultArray.length == 4) {
       $scope.showResult = true;           
       $scope.showLoader = false;
       console.log('found all search results');
   }
});
```

As Kevin points out, the best solution is to probably pass your method into whichever logic is updating the `resultArray`, which can run it as a callback after completing.

Answer (score 0):

The root of the problem here is you're trying to update properties on the `$scope` within a setInterval. Using angular's `$interval` will solve this, as will adding `$scope.apply` into the interval callback. The reason they work is they cause a digest cycle, thus causing the view to update using the new scope values.

However, it would be better to solve this problem by updating said properties at the same place where you are populating the array, thus resulting in *at least* one less digest cycle (and, the view will update sooner rather than having to wait for an interval to finish)

```
$scope.showLoader = true;
$scope.showResult = false;
someService.getData().then(function (data) {
    $scope.resultArray = data.data;
    $scope.showResult = true;
    $scope.showLoader = false;
});
```